# how to read csv file with missing columns and remove first and last delimiter of each row?

Tags: python, pandas

Dataset looks like :

[image]

how to read this and remove first and last delimiter of each row?

Comment: By first and last delimiter do you mean the square brackets?

Comment: What you are showing us an excel spreadsheet representation of the data in your csv. Please share sample data of your actual csv as well as your attempt so far to import it into a dataframe.

Comment: Yes, @kpie. I meant square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like someone just saved lists of python with a csv extension.
Maybe you can try to read those list and then transform them to a data frame. Just like this

```
with open('file.csv','r') as file:
 data = file.readlines()
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

Any ways looks like your data doesn't have the same number of columns for each row.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
import re

with open('yourFile.csv','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

data = []
for line in lines:
    print(line)
    line = re.sub(r"\[|\]|\"|\n|'","",line) #match whatever you want to remove.
    print(line)
    data.append(line.split(","))

print(data)
```

Comment: Can you explain/break down how your pattern works in re.sub? Looking at the data it looks like you are looking for square brackets and /n and replacing them with a comma.  I can't see how it is working though.

Comment: The pipe is just an or and the back slash is an escape character so it is just matching `[ or ] or " or newline or '` and replacing it with nothing.